# Select one Properties Values out of Database to put into List

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-5

If I have a database table named `Names` that has the properties: `ID`(int), `FirstName`(string), `LastName`(string).

And I want to stuff all of the `LastName`'s into a List. How would I go about doing that?

```
List<Name> lstLastNames = db.Names.ToList()?

foreach(Name n in lstLastNames)
{
    /*help*/
}
```

Is this the right track?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Name` object has a `LastName` property and you are using some type of ORM that will handle the mapping for you, you could just access it via `Name.LastName` as seen below using a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) statement :

```
// This will create a List of just your LastName properties
var lastNames = db.Names.Select(n => n.LastName).ToList();
```

This is going to be far more efficient than your previous technique, which would pull all of the data and then filter it down (as opposed to this that will *only* pull across the `LastName` properties).

With that being said, you could still use a loop-based approach as well :

```
// Define a list of strings that will store your names
var lastNames = new List<string>();
// Iterate through your objects and access the LastName property of each
foreach(Name n in db.Names)
{
     lastNames.Add(n.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I used the `Select` path.. but now I want to present that list into a view of mine.. so I have tried `ViewBag.LastNames = lastNames`, and then call that Viewbag in my view but it shows the literal scope of a List. for example `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`

Comment: How are you planning on using the List within your View? If you are using it to populate a `DropDownList()` helper, then you might be better off using a `SelectList` instead. Otherwise, you might need to try explicitly casting your ViewBag as a List via `(ViewBag.LastNames as List<string>)` or something similar.

Comment: No I don't need it as a dropdownlist.. I just need to present it as a basic list off to the side.. This table won't contain much at all..

Comment: Have you tried iterating through them as expected as in [this complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/khavDi)?

Comment: lol that is hilarious.. I had this in my View `@foreach(var item in ViewBag.Categories)
        {
            <ul>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        }` but I didn't know i needed the '@' before item lol well thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make sure you target the right ViewBag object and that you don't forget the `@` when accessing your actual name in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> lastNames = db.Names.Select(q => q.LastName).ToList();
```

This will be more efficient since you only retrieve the LastNames from Name table.